# MySQL Syntax error - table name

Tags: mysql

I'm running into a strange problem with mysql does not like my table name.

```
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS 6e0OU1QgkU7Pj6ycQF0U_results;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '6e0OU1QgkU7Pj6ycQF0U_results' at line 1

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS 6epGz4xKzfKd6A9e1ASP_results;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Any idea why the first query has a syntax error while the second query is allowed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably the `6e0`, which the SQL parser thinks is a number in scientific notation: 6 * 10<sup>0</sup>.

Comment: this sounds like a more probable answer

Comment: This is probably right, but no solution is provided...I think using quotes as Abhik suggested is probably the correct solution!

Answer (score 2):

Thats because mysql does not recognize the table name since it starts with a digit `MeN`

> Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist
>   solely of digits.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html

> It is recommended that you do not use names that begin with Me or MeN,
>   where M and N are integers. For example, avoid using 1e as an
>   identifier, because an expression such as 1e+3 is ambiguous. Depending
>   on context, it might be interpreted as the expression 1e + 3 or as the
>   number 1e+3.

You can try as

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `6e0OU1QgkU7Pj6ycQF0U_results`;
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect, which is apparent as the second example works. Also, the text you quote directly contradicts your assertion.

Comment: The reson is you can not use the identifier begins as `MeN` where M and N are digit.

Comment: I think the quotes will solve the issue but not for the reason that this answer states. This portion is irrelevant, "Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist solely of digits."...